# É possível armazenar a tmp_name de um file em cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

Tenho o seguinte código

```
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

    if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
            echo '{"status":"error"}';
            exit;
        }
        else{

            $nomesImagens = (isset($_COOKIE['nomesImagens'])) ? $_COOKIE['nomesImagens'] : '';

            if (empty($nomesImagens)) {
                setcookie("nomesImagens", $_FILES['upl']['name'], time()+300, "/");
            }
            else{
                $novoNome = $_COOKIE['nomesImagens'].",".$nomesImagens;
                setcookie("nomesImagens", $novoNome, time()+300, "/");
            }


            $tmpImagens = (isset($_COOKIE['tmpImagens'])) ? $_COOKIE['tmpImagens'] : '';

            if (empty($tmpImagens)) {
                setcookie("tmpImagens", $_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], time()+300, "/");
            }
            else{
                $novoNome = $_COOKIE['tmpImagens'].",".$tmpImagens;
                setcookie("tmpImagens", $novoNome, time()+300, "/");
            }


        }

    }

    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
```

A cada imagem selecionada ele pré-carrega a imagem e armazena a tmp_name e o name da imagem em cookies através de uma requisição ajax, porém na hora de inserir o formulário todo, os files do input somem então tenho de inserir pelos cookies que eu já gravei, ele insere no banco mas não aloca as imagens, é possível fazer isso com arquivos temporários?

Comment: Que eu saiba não. Você pode fazer o upload numa pasta temporária. Depois você pega a imagem e apaga tudo.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como pode ser feito ?

Comment: Depende da sua aplicação. É só fazer o upload da imagem numa pasta temporária com o nome da imagem. Daí você pega depois na hora de fazer o upload. Faz a cópia da imagem na pasta correta e apaga da pasta temporária.

Comment: Realmente terei de fazer isso, coloca como resposta para ficar mais organizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão é fazer o upload da imagem numa pasta temporária com o nome da imagem.

Quando for realmente inserir no banco, busque na pasta temporária a imagem visto que você tem o nome dela em sessão ou cookie. Faça uma cópia para pasta correta e depois apague a imagem da pasta temporária.

Trabalhoso, mas funciona.